# словообразовательная цепочка к слову ровный

Tags: орфография

помогите составить словообразовательную цепочку к слову ровный.

Answer (score 2):

К этому слову невозможно, оно первообразное, ОТ него - пожалуйста:

Ровный-ровнять-заровнять-заравнивать-заравнивание

Ровный-неровный-неровность